# When is it a block and when is it a lambda?

Tags: kotlin

How does the Kotlin compiler decide whether an expression enclosed in `{` `}` is a block or a lambda?

Consider this:

```
val a: Int
if (cond)
    a = 1
else
    a = 2
```

can be written more succinctly as:

```
val a =
    if (cond)
        1
    else
        2
```

Similarly, one might think that this:

```
val a: () -> Int
if (cond)
    a = { 1 }
else
    a = { 2 }
```

should be able to be written more succinctly like this:

```
val a =
    if (cond)
        { 1 }
    else
        { 2 }
```

But this is not the same: `a` is now an `Int`, and not of type `() -> Int`, because now the `{ 1 }` is no longer a lambda. What are the rules that say whether something is a lambda or a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look into the Kotlin lexer, but I guess there are few possible places in the code where the compiler expects either a single expression or a block of code. That includes the code immediately following most of control flow statements like: `if`, `else`, `while`, `when` (one of its cases), etc. If you put `{` in one of these places, it will be interpreted as a start of the block of code related to this control flow statement and not as a lambda.

This is as simple as that. Note that even if you hint the compiler about the type, it still won't work:

```kotlin
// compile error
val a: () -> Int = if (cond)
    { 1 }
else
    { 2 }
```

It will be interpreted more like this:

```kotlin
// compile error
val a: () -> Int = if (cond) {
    1
} else {
    2
}
```

`{` after `if` condition is always interpreted as a start of block of code. You need to put double `{`, `}` in cases like this:

```kotlin
// works fine
val a: () -> Int = if (cond) {
    { 1 }
} else {
    { 2 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is specified in the [Kotlin Language Specification, section 1.2: Syntax Grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#syntax-grammar):

The grammar defines a [*block*](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#grammar-rule-block) as statements between `{` and `}`. In most cases (such as function bodies) the syntax is different between a block and a lambda. Where it is the same is in the usage of [*controlStructureBody*](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#grammar-rule-controlStructureBody) - these are the places where the block has a value, or where you could put a non-block expression in its place. If you search the whole spec document for "controlStructureBody", you'll find it's used in the following places:

- For statement
- While statement
- Do-while statement
- If expression
- When expression
- When entry

In every other place where a value is required, a '{' signifies the start of a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

To put it very succinctly and easy to remember, the first opening brace after an if/when/else/for is always assumed to be the opening of a block. Use double braces if you want a lambda in there.